# Unexpected node type Element

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I have the following `XML`:

```
<Envelope>
 <Body>
  <RESULT>
   <SUCCESS>TRUE</SUCCESS>
   <RecipientId>9876543210</RecipientId>
   <ORGANIZATION_ID>12345-67890-b9e6bcd68d4fb511170ab3fcff55179d</ORGANIZATION_ID>
  </RESULT>
 </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Which I'm trying to deserialize to:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope")]
public class Add_Recipent_response
{
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string RESULT { get; set; }
    public string SUCCESS { get; set; }
    public string RecipientId { get; set; }
    public string ORGANIZATION_ID { get; set; }
}
```

With this method:

```
protected void deserializeXML(string xmlResponse)
{
    XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Add_Recipent_response));
    using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xmlResponse))
    {
        try
        {
            Add_Recipent_response XmlData = (Add_Recipent_response)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.GetBaseException());
        }
    }
}
```

This throws an exception:

> `InnerException = {"Unexpected node type Element. ReadElementString
>   method can only be called on elements with simple or empty content.
>   Line 4, position 2."}`

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can generate class from xml/json using visual studio https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh371548(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Body and Result should be a classes as well because it contains elements. Something like

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope")]
public class Add_Recipent_response
{
    public Body Body { get; set; }
}

public class Body
{
    public Result RESULT { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public string SUCCESS { get; set; }
    public string RecipientId { get; set; }
    public string ORGANIZATION_ID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm new to serialization. I'll give this a try... -EDIT- Just tried it and it works, thank you very much. I'll accept as soon as SO allows.