# Single closing XML tag isn't getting picked up when deserialising

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-deserialization

I'm using VB.NET to deserialise an XML file, the full details about my attempts to do this [are in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60762592/unexpected-node-type-element-error-when-deserialising). I'm having a problem when parsing this tag in XML:

```
<re_nokanji/>
```

It appears on its own, within `<r_ele>` and `</r_ele>` tags. Here's an example:

```
<r_ele>
<reb>アジア</reb>
<re_nokanji/>
<re_pri>gai1</re_pri>
</r_ele>
```

Here's the class definition:

```
<Serializable()>
Public Class r_ele
    <XmlElement("reb")>
    Public Property reb As String
    <XmlElement("re_pri")>
    Public Property re_pri As List(Of String)
    <XmlElement("re_inf")>
    Public Property re_inf As List(Of String)
    <XmlElement("re_restr")>
    Public Property re_restr As List(Of String)
    <XmlElement("re_nokanji")>
    Public Property re_nokanji As String
End Class
```

All the other data are deserialised just fine, so I don't think the method is the problem, but just in case it's here:

```
Dim dict As JMdict 

Sub Deserialise()
    Dim settings As XmlReaderSettings = New XmlReaderSettings
    settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse

    Dim xmlPath As String = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, jmdictpath)

    Dim serialiser As New XmlSerializer(GetType(JMdict))

    Using rdr As Xml.XmlReader = Xml.XmlReader.Create(xmlPath, settings)
        dict = CType(serialiser.Deserialize(rdr), JMdict)
    End Using
End Sub
```

I've used a separate method to check the `dict` object and none of the class objects within it have a value for the `re_nokanji` field, so it's definitely not getting picked up. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by " none of the class objects within it have a value for the re_nokanji field". Is the value null (Nothing), or is it an empty string ("")?  A null value will occur if the `ElementName` specified on the property differs in any way from the tag name including case (xml is case sensitive).

Comment: The element has no value and it is a child of reb : <re_nokanji/>  The forward slash means it is both an opening and closing tag with no value.  Because it is a child of reb you would need to create a new class reb and put it as a property in the new class.

Comment: @jdweng *it is a child of reb* ? Has something changed in the XML since this comment was made?

Comment: @jdweng - But it's not a child of reb, the reb tag opens and closes on the line above it. re_nokanji is a child of r_ele, unless I've misunderstood what you mean by child here.

Comment: @TnTinMn - That's a good point, I was checking to see whether the string value was anything other than "", but that was silly because the tag has no value, so if the tag appears it will show up as a blank string "". What I should have been searching for was whether the re_nokanji element was `Nothing`. After I did that I found that the tag had been interpreted correctly - I just hadn't checked it correctly.

Comment: Which leads me to a follow-up question - is it possible to cast this element to a Boolean type, based on whether there is a re_nokanji tag in an r_ele tag?

Comment: Actually never mind, I've figured out how - I've just set a Private element _re_nokanji as boolean, and a Public property re_nokanji as string, to which the <XmlElement("re_nokanji")> tag is added. Then in the Set statement for the property I've set the boolean element to true if the string element is not nothing, and false otherwise.

Comment: Be careful doing boolean comparisons on string types in VB using the "=" or "<>" comparison operators.  When using those operators, VB treats String.Empty ("") and a null string as equivalent.  If you want to check if a string variable equals an empty string, use `String.Empty.Equals(stringVariable)`.