# Is there a faster method to store/read data from an XML document?

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing, xml-deserialization

I've been working on a Windows form application in VB.NET to parse a large XML document, which is a Japanese-English dictionary. I originally built a string-based parser which read all the XML tags and extracted their contents manually. This took about 30 seconds on average to completely parse the XML file. At this point I had never heard of deserialisation.

Then thanks to [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60205990/is-there-a-best-practice-for-parsing-all-information-contained-within-one-parent) [users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60762592/unexpected-node-type-element-error-when-deserialising) [on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60780409/single-closing-xml-tag-isnt-getting-picked-up-when-deserialising), I got a proper XML deserialiser working, which loaded all of the data in the XML file into a class object. Brilliant. But it takes 20 seconds on average to load.

While that's a 33% improvement in efficiency, I'm wondering if there's a yet better approach I wasn't aware of or hadn't considered. Or perhaps an inefficiency in my existing code/class definitions which I can at least reduce.

The file is 4.7 million lines long, displaying information for over 180,000 dictionary entries, so I'm prepared to accept that there may be no quicker method of parsing the XML. I'm wondering if there may be some alternative way of storing the data than in an XML text-file format, which can be read by a Windows form application more quickly.

Here is the code I am currently using to deserialise:

```
Sub Deserialise()
    Dim settings As XmlReaderSettings = New XmlReaderSettings
    settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse

    Dim xmlPath As String = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, jmdictpath)

    Dim serialiser As New XmlSerializer(GetType(JMdict))

    Using rdr As Xml.XmlReader = Xml.XmlReader.Create(xmlPath, settings)
        dict = CType(serialiser.Deserialize(rdr), JMdict)
    End Using
End Sub
```

And here are the class definitions:

```
<XmlRoot>
Public Class JMdict
    <XmlElement("entry")>
    Public Property entrylist As List(Of Entry)
End Class

<Serializable()>
<XmlType("entry")>
Public Class Entry
    <XmlElement("ent_seq")>
    Public Property EntrySequence As Integer
    <XmlElement("k_ele")>
    Public Property Keywords As List(Of KeywordElement)
    <XmlElement("r_ele")>
    Public Property Readings As List(Of ReadingElement)
    <XmlElement("sense")>
    Public Property Senses As List(Of SenseElement)
End Class

<Serializable()>
<XmlType("k_ele")>
Public Class KeywordElement
    <XmlElement("keb")>
    Public Property Keyword As String
    <XmlElement("ke_pri")>
    Public Property KeywordPriority As List(Of String)
    <XmlElement("ke_inf")>
    Public Property KeywordOrthography As List(Of String)
End Class

<Serializable()>
<XmlType("r_ele")>
Public Class ReadingElement

    <XmlElement("reb")>
    Public Property Reading As String
    <XmlElement("re_pri")>
    Public Property ReadingPriority As List(Of String)
    <XmlElement("re_inf")>
    Public Property ReadingOrthography As List(Of String)
    <XmlElement("re_restr")>
    Public Property ReadingToKeywordRestriction As List(Of String)

    Private _NotTrueReading As Boolean

    <XmlElement("re_nokanji")>
    Public Property NotTrueReading As String
        Get
            Return _NotTrueReading
        End Get
        Set
            If NotTrueReading IsNot Nothing Then
                _NotTrueReading = True
            Else
                _NotTrueReading = False
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

<Serializable()>
<XmlType("sense")>
Public Class SenseElement
    <XmlElement("pos")>
    Public Property PartOfSpeech As List(Of String)
    <XmlElement("gloss")>
    Public Property Gloss As List(Of GlossElement)

    <XmlElement("stagk")>
    Public Property SenseRestrictedToKeyword As List(Of String)
    <XmlElement("stagr")>
    Public Property SenseRestrictedToReading As List(Of String)

    <XmlElement("xref")>
    Public Property CrossReference As List(Of String)
    <XmlElement("ant")>
    Public Property Antonym As List(Of String)
    <XmlElement("field")>
    Public Property Field As List(Of String)
    <XmlElement("dial")>
    Public Property Dialect As List(Of String)
    <XmlElement("s_inf")>
    Public Property SenseInformation As List(Of String)
    <XmlElement("misc")>
    Public Property Misc As List(Of String)
    <XmlElement("lsource")>
    Public Property LanguageSource As List(Of LanguageSourceElement)
End Class


<Serializable()>
<XmlType("gloss")>
Public Class GlossElement
    <XmlAttribute("xml:lang")>
    Public Property Language As String
    <XmlAttribute("g_type")>
    Public Property GlossType As String
    <XmlText>
    Public Property Text As String
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Text
    End Function
End Class

<Serializable()>
<XmlType("lsource")>
Public Class LanguageSourceElement
    <XmlAttribute("xml:lang")>
    Public Property Language As String
    <XmlAttribute("ls_type")>
    Public Property LanguageSourceType As String

    Private _IsWaseieigo As Boolean
    <XmlAttribute("ls_wasei")>
    Public Property IsWaseieigo As String
        Get
            Return _IsWaseieigo
        End Get
        Set
            If IsWaseieigo = "y" Then
                _IsWaseieigo = True
            Else
                _IsWaseieigo = False
            End If
            '_IsWaseieigo = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    <XmlText>
    Public Property Text As String
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Text
    End Function

End Class
```

What do we think? Is there any hope for a quicker solution?

**EDIT** - Here's a sample of the XML:

```
<entry>
<ent_seq>1486440</ent_seq>
<k_ele>
<keb>美術</keb>
<ke_pri>ichi1</ke_pri>
<ke_pri>news1</ke_pri>
<ke_pri>nf02</ke_pri>
</k_ele>
<r_ele>
<reb>びじゅつ</reb>
<re_pri>ichi1</re_pri>
<re_pri>news1</re_pri>
<re_pri>nf02</re_pri>
</r_ele>
<sense>
<pos>&n;</pos>
<pos>&adj-no;</pos>
<gloss>art</gloss>
<gloss>fine arts</gloss>
</sense>
<sense>
<gloss xml:lang="dut">kunst</gloss>
<gloss xml:lang="dut">schone kunsten</gloss>
</sense>
<sense>
<gloss xml:lang="fre">art</gloss>
<gloss xml:lang="fre">beaux-arts</gloss>
</sense>
<sense>
<gloss xml:lang="ger">Kunst</gloss>
<gloss xml:lang="ger">die schönen Künste</gloss>
<gloss xml:lang="ger">bildende Kunst</gloss>
</sense>
<sense>
<gloss xml:lang="ger">Produktionsdesign</gloss>
<gloss xml:lang="ger">Szenographie</gloss>
</sense>
<sense>
<gloss xml:lang="hun">művészet</gloss>
<gloss xml:lang="hun">művészeti</gloss>
<gloss xml:lang="hun">művészi</gloss>
<gloss xml:lang="hun">rajzóra</gloss>
<gloss xml:lang="hun">szépművészet</gloss>
</sense>
<sense>
<gloss xml:lang="rus">изящные искусства; искусство</gloss>
<gloss xml:lang="rus">{～{的}} художественный, артистический</gloss>
</sense>
<sense>
<gloss xml:lang="slv">umetnost</gloss>
<gloss xml:lang="slv">likovna umetnost</gloss>
</sense>
<sense>
<gloss xml:lang="spa">bellas artes</gloss>
</sense>
</entry>
```

And the whole thing is wrapped in the tags

Comment: How often does the xml file change?  i.e. Does your end use really need to read this file every time?  What I'm getting at, is would your application be better served by using a database that was originally populated from the xml data?

Comment: The XML file changes not at all, and the application may well be better served by connecting to a database. I've even written code to transfer all the data to a database, but for some reason I didn't think reading the data would be as quick as parsing it on the fly...

Comment: I'll give that a go ...

Comment: Don't use serialization.  It is very slow.  Linq is much quicker than serialization.  A few week ago an OP tried the experiment and where serialization was taking 30 seconds to a minute, xml linq returned results instantly.  I suspect there was a memory issue that made the big difference.  When memory is low extra memory is gained by using disk space for swapping.  Disk is much slower than memory.

Comment: Can you post the XML file up for us to try a few things?

Comment: Assuming 4.7m lines means about 20Mb, parsing time of 20s seems very slow. I normally reckon 1Gb minute or 15Mb/second is a reasonable parsing speed.

Comment: Hi @CaiusJard, I've added in a sample of the XML, and the full file is available online to download from this link: http://www.edrdg.org/jmdict/j_jmdict.html. Where it says "current version (Unicode UTF8)"

Answer (score 1):

Try xml linq.  The code below is not tested since you did not post any xml. :

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Imports System.IO
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim JMdict As JMdict = JMdict.Parse(FILENAME)
    End Sub

    Public Class JMdict
        Public Property entrylist As List(Of Entry)

        Public Shared Function Parse(filename As String) As JMdict
            Dim reader As New StreamReader(filename)
            reader.ReadLine()
            Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(reader)
            Dim newJMdict As New JMdict()
            Dim jmDict = doc.Root

            newJMdict.entrylist = jmDict.Elements("entry").Select(Function(x) Entry.Parse(x)).ToList()
            Return newJMdict
        End Function
    End Class

    Public Class Entry
        Public Property EntrySequence As Integer
        Public Property Keywords As List(Of KeywordElement)
        Public Property Readings As List(Of ReadingElement)
        Public Property Senses As List(Of SenseElement)

        Public Shared Function Parse(xEntry As XElement) As Entry
            Dim newEntry As New Entry()
            newEntry.EntrySequence = CType(xEntry.Element("ent_seq"), Integer)
            newEntry.Keywords = xEntry.Elements("k_ele").Select(Function(x) KeywordElement.Parse(x)).ToList()

            newEntry.Readings = xEntry.Elements("r_ele").Select(Function(x) ReadingElement.Parse(x)).ToList()
            newEntry.Senses = xEntry.Elements("sense").Select(Function(x) SenseElement.Parse(x)).ToList()


            Return newEntry
        End Function
    End Class

    Public Class KeywordElement
        Public Property Keyword As String
        Public Property KeywordPriority As List(Of String)
        Public Property KeywordOrthography As List(Of String)

        Public Shared Function Parse(xKeywordElement As XElement) As KeywordElement
            Dim newKeywordElement As New KeywordElement()
            newKeywordElement.Keyword = CType(xKeywordElement.Element("key"), String)
            newKeywordElement.KeywordPriority = xKeywordElement.Elements("ke_pri").Select(Function(x) CType(x, String)).ToList()
            newKeywordElement.KeywordOrthography = xKeywordElement.Elements("ke_inf").Select(Function(x) CType(x, String)).ToList()

            Return newKeywordElement
        End Function


    End Class

    Public Class ReadingElement

        Public Property Reading As String
        Public Property ReadingPriority As List(Of String)
        Public Property ReadingOrthography As List(Of String)
        Public Property ReadingToKeywordRestriction As List(Of String)

        Private _NotTrueReading As Boolean

        Public Property NotTrueReading As String
            Get
                Return _NotTrueReading
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                If NotTrueReading IsNot Nothing Then
                    _NotTrueReading = True
                Else
                    _NotTrueReading = False
                End If
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Shared Function Parse(xReadingElement As XElement) As ReadingElement
            Dim newReadingElement As New ReadingElement
            newReadingElement.Reading = CType(xReadingElement.Element("reb"), String)
            newReadingElement.ReadingPriority = xReadingElement.Elements("re_pri").Select(Function(x) CType(x, String)).ToList()
            newReadingElement.ReadingOrthography = xReadingElement.Elements("re_inf").Select(Function(x) CType(x, String)).ToList()
            newReadingElement.ReadingToKeywordRestriction = xReadingElement.Elements("re_restr").Select(Function(x) CType(x, String)).ToList()

            newReadingElement.NotTrueReading = CType(xReadingElement.Element("re_nokanji"), String)

            Return newReadingElement
        End Function
    End Class

    Public Class SenseElement
        Public Property PartOfSpeech As List(Of String)
        Public Property Gloss As List(Of GlossElement)

        Public Property SenseRestrictedToKeyword As List(Of String)
        Public Property SenseRestrictedToReading As List(Of String)
        Public Property CrossReference As List(Of String)
        Public Property Antonym As List(Of String)
        Public Property Field As List(Of String)
        Public Property Dialect As List(Of String)
        Public Property SenseInformation As List(Of String)
        Public Property Misc As List(Of String)
        Public Property LanguageSource As List(Of LanguageSourceElement)

        Public Shared Function Parse(xSenseElement As XElement) As SenseElement
            Dim newSenseElement As New SenseElement
            newSenseElement.PartOfSpeech = xSenseElement.Elements("pos").Select(Function(x) CType(x, String)).ToList()
            newSenseElement.Gloss = xSenseElement.Elements("gloss").Select(Function(x) GlossElement.Parse(x)).ToList()
            newSenseElement.SenseRestrictedToKeyword = xSenseElement.Elements("stagk").Select(Function(x) CType(x, String)).ToList()
            newSenseElement.SenseRestrictedToReading = xSenseElement.Elements("stagr").Select(Function(x) CType(x, String)).ToList()
            newSenseElement.CrossReference = xSenseElement.Elements("xref").Select(Function(x) CType(x, String)).ToList()
            newSenseElement.Antonym = xSenseElement.Elements("ant").Select(Function(x) CType(x, String)).ToList()
            newSenseElement.Field = xSenseElement.Elements("field").Select(Function(x) CType(x, String)).ToList()
            newSenseElement.Dialect = xSenseElement.Elements("dial").Select(Function(x) CType(x, String)).ToList()
            newSenseElement.SenseInformation = xSenseElement.Elements("s_inf").Select(Function(x) CType(x, String)).ToList()
            newSenseElement.Misc = xSenseElement.Elements("misc").Select(Function(x) CType(x, String)).ToList()

            newSenseElement.LanguageSource = xSenseElement.Elements("lsource").Select(Function(x) LanguageSourceElement.Parse(x)).ToList()
            Return newSenseElement
        End Function
    End Class

    Public Class GlossElement
        Public Property Language As String
        Public Property GlossType As String
        Public Property Text As String

        Public Shared Function Parse(xGlossElement As XElement) As GlossElement
            Dim newGlossElement As New GlossElement

            newGlossElement.Language = CType(xGlossElement.Attributes().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "lang").FirstOrDefault(), String)
            newGlossElement.GlossType = CType(xGlossElement.Attribute("g_type"), String)
            newGlossElement.Text = CType(xGlossElement, String)
            Return newGlossElement
        End Function
    End Class

    Public Class LanguageSourceElement

        Public Property Language As String
        Public Property LanguageSourceType As String

        Public IsWaseieigo As Boolean

        Public Property Text As String

        Public Shared Function Parse(xLanguageSourceElement As XElement) As LanguageSourceElement
            Dim newLanguageSourceElement As New LanguageSourceElement
            newLanguageSourceElement.Language = CType(xLanguageSourceElement.Attributes().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "lang").FirstOrDefault(), String)
            newLanguageSourceElement.LanguageSourceType = CType(xLanguageSourceElement.Attribute("ls_type"), String)
            newLanguageSourceElement.IsWaseieigo = IIf(CType(xLanguageSourceElement.Attribute("ls_wasei"), String) = "y", True, False)
            newLanguageSourceElement.Text = CType(xLanguageSourceElement, String)
            Return newLanguageSourceElement
        End Function

    End Class
End Module
```

Comment: Thanks jdweng! I've updated the question with a sample of the XML File. As soon as I get the chance to try this out I'll let you know how it goes :)

Comment: I just fixed 3 issues 1) I used Parse instead of Load in one place 2) Had to add fix for unicode characters 3) Had to add  ToList() in a lot of places.  I'm not did not fully check to see if every object got parsed correctly.  I may still have some typo errors.

Comment: I just changed one line after testing.  It took 11 seconds to read entire file.